# <apex:actionFunction not calling Apex methods

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, actionfunction

I am trying to call an apex method from my visualforce page using javascript method.

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" expires="" sidebar="false" title="Connection" controller="ConnectionController">
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/21.0/apex.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function closeWindow() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.close();
            CallApexMethod();
       }, 10000);
    }
    window.onload = closeWindow();
    </script>
    <apex:form id="callApexMethod">
        <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!retrieveMethod}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And my controller is:

```
public class ConnectionController {
    public PageReference retrieveMethod() {
          System.debug('Inside Method');
          // some logic
          return null;
    }
}
```

It is not even printing System.debug in my logs. 
Not sure If I am missing something.
I know there is a way to do it with javascript remoting as well but its a very small part and can be done by 
So I was trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you first close the window and then call the methods. Try to change there order

```
CallApexMethod();
window.close();
```

or it will be better if you call `window.close();` from `oncomplete` of your action function.

Comment: nope.. actually `CallApexMethod()` is returning null thats why I have to put it after `window.close();`

Comment: I have alert on `oncomplete` but i never came.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Tushar's Answer add  `reRender`

```
<apex:form id="callApexMethod">
    <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!retrieveMethod}"   reRender="callApexMethod"/>
</apex:form>
```